# fetch_object on inherited class

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm having a problem when using the [MySQLi fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) function to instantiate a class...and maybe I'm just going about this all wrong.

I have a CustomerAddress class than extends an Address class:

```
class Address {
    private $street;
    private $city;
    private $zip;
    private $state;

    public function getStreet(){
        return $this->street;
    }
}

class CustomerAddress extends Address {
    private $fName;
    private $lName;

    public function getNames(){
        return $this->fName;
    }
}

function getCustomerAddresses($someID){
    $db = "db connection here";
    $query = "SELECT `street`, `city`, `zip`, `state`, `fName`, `lName` ...";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $someID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object("CustomerAddress")){
        var_dump($obj);
    }

    //...
}
```

That var_dump returns this:

```
object(CustomerAddress)#32 (23) {
  ["fName":"customeraddress":private]=>
  string(4) "John"
  ["lName":"customeraddress":private]=>
  string(5) "Smith"
  ["street":"address":private]=>
  NULL
  ["city":"address":private]=>
  NULL
  ["state":"address":private]=>
  NULL
  ["zip":"address":private]=>
  NULL
  ["street"]=>
  string(11) "Some Street"
  ["city"]=>
  string(7) "Anytown"
  ["state"]=>
  string(10) "Some State"
  ["zip"]=>
  string(5) "12345"
}
```

So as far as I can tell, it won't populate the variables from the parent class, but instead creates new ones.  Surely it's just me being stupid with inheritance or using the fetch_object incorrectly because I can't find anyone else having this problem (nor have I had a problem doing this with a regular class).

Comment: How is your code connecting the `getCustomerAddresses` function with the two classes? I don't see the objects getting created anywhere.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I'm trying to populate the CustomerAddress class with the fields from my database.  That's what I use fetch_object for.

Comment: Also, there's an autoloader (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) that autoloads the class name.  Guess I should include that in the code...

Comment: _Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member_

Comment: Ahhh @AbraCadaver that's it.  Those need to be protected instead?

Comment: Yes, protected or public depending on your needs.

Comment: Shouldn't `$street` ,`$city`, `$zip` , `$state` in `Address` class be protected ?

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it.  Talk about a brain fart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you declared the variables `private`.  Try making them `protected` instead.

`private` means that only the declaring class has access to the variables.  Since the variables in `Address` are private, `CustomerAddress` subclass can't access them. This is probably affecting `fetch_object()` when it tries to create a `CustomerAddress`.

`protected` on the other hand means "only this class and subclasses" have access, which appears to be what you need.